# TTS to support Chinese characters/speech

Tags: java, text-to-speech, chinese-locale

I'm going to develop a tool which can convert the text to speech. Of course support for Chinese characters would be quite important. If not, the TTS would be great choice if the internet access would be natable, I can use the Google translate API. Unfortunately not all places using my tool would have the internet access, I'm wondering if there is another way to accomplish this task?

I've searched in the internet, and the espeak would be a nice solution. But I have to encapsulate the DLL.

Is there any better solution for my requirements?

Comment: I was editing that & came to *"if the internet access would be natable"*, I would have corrected it if I had an idea what you meant by 'natable'.  Can you think of another word to replace it?  Also, this is about supporting Chinese characters **and speech**, right?

Comment: *"But I have to encapsulate the DLL."*  That is not a big problem, so long as it also comes with the natives for OS X & *nix.